# Using the Google API's in Apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to call the googles API with apps script?

I saw this example:

```
var url = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?'
    + 'q=skateboarding+dog'
    + '&start-index=21'
    + '&max-results=10'
    + '&v=2';
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
Logger.log(response);
```

But what i would like is to get all deleted users in the Apps domain with this:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users
?domain=primary domain name&pageToken=token for next results page
&maxResults=max number of results per page
&showDeleted=true
```

Is it possible, do i need to add the oAuth settings before, how should that be?

Now that Advanced services are aviable and i can use ADMIN SDK it should be possible? But how do i format the GET code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Domain service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/domain/) of Apps Script.

```
 var users = UserManager.getAllUsers();
 for (var i in users) {
   Logger.log(users[i].getEmail());
 }
```

Comment: Yeye i know, but i need to undelete all deleted users, and there is nothing built in in apps script as i see it. I need to use the full APIs?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that, but it's not so easy to get a token...
You may found some informations on this [site](https://sites.google.com/a/ousset.net/orgasm-library/) (don't get scared for the name it was just a bad joke).
what you are looking for is the [dioxygen library](https://sites.google.com/a/ousset.net/orgasm-library/home/dioxygen-library) in the sources there is the whole process to get a token. (I'm building something much more simpler actually if you are interested for the future let me know)

Comment: got that (but not totally finished yet) https://sites.google.com/a/ousset.net/harold-s-pages/stuff/minioauth2-library